# Making a contour-enhanced funnel plot for a RE meta-analysis

Tags: r

I am trying to make a contour-enhanced funnel plot for a random-effects meta-analysis model. I am using the `funnel.rma()` function from the `meta` package. The problem I am running into is that the funnel-shaped diagonal lines (confidence intervals) that come off of the vertical line that represents the summary estimate are only showing up for the fixed-effect estimate. I can make the vertical line for the FE estimate go away, but I can't get the diagonal lines to attach themselves to the vertical line for the RE estimate.

The data I am using are

The code I am using is as follows:

```
require(meta) 
g <-  c(0.88,  0.66, -0.02,  0.34,  0.30, -0.12,  0.70,  0.42,  2.66, 0.10,  0.73, -0.54,      0.72, -0.54)
g_v <- c(0.12, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06, 0.09, 0.08, 0.03, 0.07, 0.10, 0.06, 0.11, 0.07, 0.13, 0.06)
g_se <- sqrt(g_v)
FC<-metagen(g, g_se, method.tau = "REML", hakn = TRUE, comb.fixed = FALSE) 
funnel(FC, lty.random = 1, xlim = c(-3, 3), xlab = "Effect size",  ylab = "Standard Error", cex = .75, col = 1, bg = 1, contour=c(0.00001, 0.95), col.contour=c("grey", "white"), family = "serif", cex.lab = 1.5)
```

Comment: If you could make your example reproducible, that would make it easier to answer.  (We don't have access to your data, so we don't know what's happening. I could try it with my data, but then I wouldn't know if the problem was happening.)

Comment: Yes, of course. Good point. I've added the data to the post.

Comment: You need reproducible code. That's not what you gave me. I've now corrected it so it actually runs.  You're not using funnel.rma() (that's in the metafor package) , you're using funnel() from the meta package.  I'm trying to help, but you're not making it easy for me. :)  Next question: what are you expecting?

Comment: I had to add the line to change g_v to g_se. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, again, good point. You need to input g_se when using metagen(). Sorry, I'm bouncing back and forth between the two packages and I got mixed up. I'm not totally sure how to answer the question of what I'm expecting. The diagonal lines are attached to the FE summary line, but I would like them to be attached to the RE summary line (and then I'll delete the FE summary line). Does that answer your question at all? Thanks for the help!

Comment: OK, I don't know. I don't use metagen often, and I've never used it's funnel() function. You mentioned funnel.rma(), which is the metafor function, and if you've loaded metafor, then funnel() works. I use that a lot. I'm still  not sure what a 'contoured' funnel plot is - is that different from a regular funnel plot?

Comment: Yeah, it's a little different. It's a funnel plot with p value areas marked around the null region. This gives you a little extra info about what types of asymmetry you have. If the missing region of the funnel seems to be around the area of nonsignificance, then that's an indication that pub bias is causing the asymmetry, rather than some other "small-study effect."

Comment: I have the same problem, although I am using the regular funnel plot and not the contoured one. But for me too, the funnel itself (the diagonal lines) center themselves to the fixed effect even when I disable the fixed effect from my meta object. Did you find the solution?